# How to create a exe file for python program with spacy without using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, spacy

I am trying to package my Python program which contains spacy. I tried with pyinstaller using hidden imports and created a exe file. But I am always getting the following error:

```
 "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI66162\\thinc\\neural\\_custom_kernels.cu'".
```

Please Help me with this problem or let me know if there is any other way to create package file..

```
Python : 3.7.0
Spacy: 2.2.3
```

Comment: How does your setup.py look like?

Comment: I wasn't using any setup file .. I have created exe file for other programs ...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same problem, and I ultimately I gave up and rolled back spacy to version 2.2.1, and somehow I was able to compile my program on pyinstaller without any problems.

```
pip install spacy==2.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the additional hooks and extended paths? See link below

[spacy 2.2.3 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'thinc\\neural\\_custom_kernels.cu' in pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645155/spacy-2-2-3-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-thinc-neur)

It worked for me in a normal (not a virtual environment).

The FileNotFound error is because PyInstaller isn't packaging thinc properly; thinc needed a hook. I've found that as script containing from spacy import * will work with the hook file below. The command I used was:

pyinstaller test-spacy.py --additional-hooks-dir=.

Simply copy the below text into a file called hook-spacy.py, that's in the same directory as your script.

```
# HOOK FILE FOR SPACY
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- SPACY -----------------------------
data = collect_all('spacy')

datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]

# ----------------------------- THINC -----------------------------
data = collect_all('thinc')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- CYMEM -----------------------------
data = collect_all('cymem')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- PRESHED -----------------------------
data = collect_all('preshed')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- BLIS -----------------------------

data = collect_all('blis')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]
# This hook file is a bit of a hack - really, all of the libraries should be in seperate hook files. (Eg hook-blis.py with the blis part of the hook)
```

Also adjust .spec file and added main.spec file with below details and it works.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

import PyInstaller

datas = []
datas.extend(PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files('spacy.lang', include_py_files = True))
datas.extend(PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files('thinc'))

block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=['D:\\rajesh\\python\\console\\live'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=datas,
         hiddenimports = [
            'spacy.kb',
            'spacy.lexeme',
            'spacy.matcher._schemas',
            'spacy.morphology',
            'spacy.parts_of_speech',
            'spacy.syntax._beam_utils',
            'spacy.syntax._parser_model',
            'spacy.syntax.arc_eager',
            'spacy.syntax.ner',
            'spacy.syntax.nn_parser',
            'spacy.syntax.stateclass',
            'spacy.syntax.transition_system',
            'spacy.tokens._retokenize',
            'spacy.tokens.morphanalysis',
            'spacy.tokens.underscore',

            'spacy._align',

            'blis',
            'blis.py',

            'cymem',
            'cymem.cymem',

            'murmurhash',
            'murmurhash.mrmr',

            'preshed.maps',

            'srsly.msgpack.util',

            'thinc.extra.search',
            'thinc.linalg',
            'thinc.neural._aligned_alloc',
            'thinc.neural._custom_kernels',

            'sklearn.utils._cython_blas',
            'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs',
            'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree',
            'sklearn.tree._utils'
        ],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
   pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      [],
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='main',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
   coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,/
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           upx_exclude=[],
           name='main')
```